# How to plot Hog features in the image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, plot, feature-extraction

I am trying to feature extraction from an image for some certain points. First time I am using HogFeatureextraction. When I plot the features and valid points, I am getting result not on the certain points. I will use these features for training later on. For example, I have points on the straight line. Should not my features on where my certain points on the line. I am a little bit confused about concept of it. I used [features,validPoints] = extractHOGFeatures(I,points). x and y are my 10 positions in the image. In this case how is feature extraction working?

`[features,validPoints] = extractHOGFeatures(I,[x,y]);
figure; 
imshow(I); 
hold on; 
plot(features, 'ro'); 
plot(validPoints,'go');`

Thank you

Comment: Show a [mcve], please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [function's documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extracthogfeatures.html) explains it all clearly.

[`validPoints`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extracthogfeatures.html#outputarg_validPoints) is a `nX2` matrix of xy coordinates so you should use `plot(x,y)` instead of `plot(x)` to plot it.

[`features`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extracthogfeatures.html#outputarg_features) is a matrix of the HoG features of each point, and simply plot it using `plot(features, 'ro')` will not produce any reasonable output.

However, you can simply obtain the third output (`visualization`) from [`extractHOGFeatures`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extracthogfeatures.html) and then use `plot` to plot it:

```
I = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
% desired points
n = 20;
x = randi(size(I,2), [n 1]);
y = randi(size(I,1), [n 1]);
% extract features + visualization object
[features,validPoints,visualization] = extractHOGFeatures(I,[x,y]);
% show image and features
figure;
imshow(I);
hold on;
plot(visualization,'Color','r');
% plot valid points
plot(validPoints(:,1),validPoints(:,2),'go');
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for help and explanation. I could not think about plotting 2 coordinates.